# ItemView event not working when triggered in onClose handler

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette CollectonView that is listening for an event in its child views as follows:

```
    this.on(this, 'itemview:timeline:storyRemoved', this._storyRemoved);
```

The itemview triggers the event during its onClose:

```
onClose: function () {
    this.trigger('timeline:storyRemoved', { model: this.model });
}
```

But the _storyRemoved function is never called.

If I move the trigger to onShow then it works fine:

```
onShow: function () {
    this.trigger('timeline:storyRemoved', { model: this.model });
}
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the fact that the view has been closed and is therefore not in the collection view any longer?

Any way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the view is not listening because it has already been closed when you trigger the event.

Depending on what you're doing, shouldn't the model itself trigger this event? That way, you could add something like this in your collection view:

```
collectionEvents: {
  'remove': '_storyRemoved'
}
```

[As you can see here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-80), Removing a model will trigger a remove event with a reference to the model that was removed.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried that first, but found that the itemview hadn't yet been removed from the collectionview when this event was triggered. I need the DOM to be up-to-date so that I can restructure the remaining items. What I've done so far is exactly what you suggest, but used a settimeout of 1ms to ensure the DOM is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I like gbsice's point here, and I also wanted to add a more general answer: you can use `onBeforeClose` rather than `onClose` if you need something executed prior to the `close` event.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#onbeforeclose-callback

So in your case, it would be

```
onBeforeClose: function () {
  this.trigger('timeline:storyRemoved', { model: this.model });
}
```

Comment: I think the problem with this solution is that if you look [here](http://marionettejs.com/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-228), you can see that the collection view stops listening to the item view *before* calling the `close` method on the item view, which itself triggers the `onBeforeClose` and `onClose` method. That means that even `onBeforeClose` would not work in this case.

Comment: I don't see it... if that was the case, what would be the purpose of `onBeforeClose`?

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that event. I'll give it a go and report back!

Comment: @tyler I believe the purpose of onBeforeClose is to do any kind of DOM handling before the item view DOM is cleared. It's more about the DOM of the view itself instead of being about the `ItemView` being removed from the `CollectionView`